# Keep Chrome extensions when debugging JS in WebStorm

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webstorm

When I debug in WebStorm (Angular) it launches a new session Chrome browser but removed all extensions, however I would like to keep the Redux extension in the debug session. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

WebStorm uses Chrome protocol with `--remote-debugging-port` option for debugging by default. Debug session is started in a new window and using a new custom Chrome profile (as, if Chrome is already started, a debugging port can't be opened for any new or existing Chrome instance that has the same user data).

You can modify Chrome settings in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers** to launch Chrome with your own user data - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-debugger.html#ws_js_debug_default_chrome_user_data. But you will then need to make sure to close all running Chrome instances prior to starting the debug session to make debugging work